# ImportError when importing QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

Tags: python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, import, importerror

I'm trying to import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem for a QGIS plugin but it keeps complaining about either trying the Core, Gui, or Widget modules.

The import line reads:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsCoordinateTransform, QgsProject
```

The error looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`Qgs*` classes are not part of **Qt** but of **QGIS**. Your three classes are in the [`qgis.core`](https://api.qgis.org/api/group__core.html) module:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsCoordinateTransform, QgsProject
```